# Get distinct row from libraries

Tags: document-library

I have a order list by region (NWOrders, SWOrders, etc.). Is there a way to get distinct record by Customer. For example, Customer Roger Nigel has 70+ orders in the NWOrders library, John Doe has bunch of orders in the SEOrders library. I just need to get distinct customers from each library.

The reason for this is compare all the customers in the various orders library against customerLibrary to see who has not placed any orders so marketing can target those customers.

How do I get unique customers from each library?

Comment: Please tag your post appropriately. Do you use custom code?

Comment: Powershell would work but it's for the marketing dept and they want to see the data on a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following CAML query to find the distinct customers

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='CustomerName' /></OrderBy>";
DataTable dtcamltest = oList.GetItems(query).GetDataTable();
DataView dtview = new DataView(dtcamltest);
DataTable dtdistinct = dtview.ToTable(true, "CustomerName");
//dtdistinct will contain distinct values
```

**Update**

You can modify the XSL of the content query webpart and use

```
<xsl:template match="/" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20">
   <xsl:variable name="unique-list" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[not(@Title=following::Row/@Title)]" />
   <xsl:for-each select="$unique-list">
   <xsl:value-of select="@Title" />
   </xsl:for-each>        
</xsl:template>
```

http://blog-sharepoint.blogspot.com/2011/03/sharepoint-list-distinct-unique-values.html

Comment: Hi Amal, thanks for the CAML query. Is there a way to use this with Content Query Webpart?